# How to extract Entity like name , address using NLTK 2.0.4 and Python 2.6.6

Tags: nltk, python-2.6

I am trying to extract name and address from free text using NLTK 2.0.4 and Python 2.6.6 using below code. However getting error that "global name 'ne_chunk_sents' is not defined". Not sure what would be the fix please help ? Or is there any better way to handle this scenario ?
I tried with batch_ne_chunk but no luck.

```
def package_get_entities(self,text):
    #text = text[0:300]
    entity_names = []
    chunked = self.get_chunked_sentences(text)
    for tree in chunked:
        entity_names.extend(self.extract_entity_names(tree))
    entity_names = list(set(entity_names))
    return entity_names

def get_chunked_sentences(self,text):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
    tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
    chunked_sentences =nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
    return chunked_sentences

def extract_entity_names(self,t):
    entity_names = []
    if hasattr(t, 'node') and t.node:
        if t.node == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(self.extract_entity_names(child))
    return entity_names
```

Comment: Seriously?! NLTK v2.0.4? Python 2.6? It's like Python3.6++ now with NLTK v3.2.4 -_-|||

Comment: First upgrade your python and `pip install -U nltk`

Comment: I agree with you , but funny part is that for the time being I need to manage with this combination. Can you suggest how can I apply Regx parser and build custom chunking ?

Comment: Create  Docker image and the install the latest Python and NLTk inside the docker. Do everything you need in the Docker. Forget about your host machine... Or perhaps find another job that don't do this to you =)

Comment: @alvas you may right but some time we need to work with limited support comparing what we expecting. You are lucky that you get what you want :), anyway thanks I found some alternative to build my annotator.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if it's possible to share, which system are you working on? It's because NLTK recently dropped support for Python2.6 and some new regression test code would even skipped support for Python2.7. So it'll be good for the devs to know which/what kind of systems are still working with Python2.6 =)